# Эмуляция flash накопителя . NFS сервер?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, raspberry-pi, mount

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь подключить Raspberry PI 2 на базе Raspbian ос к стороннему девайсу для просмотра фотографий через USB.
Стало интересно, как сэмулировать "флешку" со стороны линукс системы на Raspberry? Возможно ли это сделать через NFS сервер?
Подключая Raspberry, устройство должно его распознавать как обычный флеш накопитель и смотреть в определенную папку с фотографиями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NFS` - это `network file system`. А `usb` - не `network`. Так что не то. Для подключения по USB надо реализовать `usb mass storage`. И на самом деле с подключением есть сразу две проблемы:

Во-первых, аппаратная. Шина USB требует участия мастера (хост-контроллер) и ведомых устройств. `USB OTG` (смартфоны и т.д.) включает реализацию и мастера и ведомого на одном и том же порту. Но для самого стандарта USB это не требуется, и контроллер может не поддерживать работу в качестве ведомого. Мне удалось найти ответ про [первый raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4938):

> The model B has a built in 2 port USB hub, which does not know how to act as a USB device. The model A directly connects the processor USB interface, which can be configured either as a USB device or USB host.

На сколько я знаю, rpi 2 так же сделан через USB-хаб. Т.е. как подключаемое устройство выступать скорей всего не сможет.

Во-вторых, преграда программная. Для режима `mass storage` нужна программная поддержка со стороны ОС. В ядре `linux` есть модуль [`g_mass_storage`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179573), возможно по-умолчанию сборка этого модуля не производится и ядро вам надо будет пересобрать.

Напоследок, технически возможна софтовая реализация USB на `GPIO` портах. Но это крайне медленно будет работать, и довольно трудозатратно по части написания и отладки.